# 'And' 'Or' condition using stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a question about using stored procedure in SQL Server 2005.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tst_user_sp]  
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
    @p1 nvarchar = null,    
    @p2 nvarchar = null AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here 
    SELECT state 
    FROM tst_user 
    WHERE user_id = @p1 AND user_pwd = @p2; 
END
```

My expected output is to get the value of the 'state'. It returned an empty record.

But, after changing the `And` to `Or`, I got the output. Why can't I get the output by using `And`?

My sql query:

```
exec tst_user_sp 'lackh', 's'
```

Comment: Do you have the correct data to return for 'and' statement?

Comment: Ever heard of truth tables? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Comment: Because no row has both the `user_id` and `user_pwd` that you want.  Hence, the stored procedure returns nothing.

Comment: yes i have,but the condition is both should get satisfied.

Comment: Not related to the immediate problem, but the fact that you could actually do such a query is a strong indication that the password may be stored in plaintext, which is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea if this is related to the problem you are seeing, but your stored procedure has a major problem.  The definition is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tst_user_sp]  
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
@p1 nvarchar = null,    
@p2 nvarchar = null AS
```

This uses the *default* length for the `nvarchar` fields, and the default varies by context.  You should *always* use a length when using string types in SQL.  Something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tst_user_sp] (
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
    @p1 nvarchar(4000) = null,    
    @p2 nvarchar(4000) = null
) AS
```

Given what you are doing in the procedure, any use of the default values will result in no value being returned, because of the way the `where` clause is defined.

Comment: And the *default length* for a `NVARCHAR` parameter is ***1 character*** ! Usually not what one expects and wants ...